# What happens when you start New Game+?

Tags: defenders-quest

I have finished both branches at the end of the main game, and am considering starting a New Game+.

What carries over from the current game to the second playthrough?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Absolutely everything but the story itself.  You won't have any of your followers at first, but as soon as you hit the point in the story where they join you, (ie. when Slak joins, you get all your barbarians back) you can use all members of that class, with their levels, skills, and equipment intact.

Even Azra's level and tomes you collected carry over!

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that New Game+ contains several new elements, such as side-quests and the ability to upgrade weapons/armor.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft That has nothing to do with what carries over into NG+.  Yeah, it's got extra stuff, but it doesn't carry over from the main game, because it's not in the main game, only NG+.

Comment: Also, note that you can use NG+ items/levels/etc back in the original game (to finish out some extreme levels, for example).