# What is game+ in Defenders Quest: Valley of the Forgotten

Tags: defenders-quest

I've seen quite a few references to it in the achievements but I'm not sure what it is or how I access it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It refers to the game's New Game+ mode, a mode unlocked when you finish the game, where you can play the game a second time but with various things carried from your original save to the new game.

For more information about New Game+, see the related question: [What happens when you start New Game+?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/92747/what-happens-when-you-start-new-game)